# how can I print objects in a model as options

Tags: python, html, django, api

my html

```
 <select multiple class="form-control" name="tags">
         <option value="">{% for tag in Tag %}
                           {{ tag }}
                          {% endfor %}
         </option>
 </select>
```

my views.py

```
def CreateView(request, pk=None):
    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
    args = {'Tag':queryset}
    return render(request, 'home/create.html', args)
```

i wrote my code like this but it is printing them as one option oh and i am still a beginner
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop is inside the option tag, you need to have it on the outer side to create one option per tag

```
 {% for tag in Tag %}
 <option value="">{{ tag }}</option>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank u but is there a way to make the value pk? not str because the form is not accepting str thank u